# Fitting results from a PRNG into a max min range

Tags: java

I am using PRNGs from the Java Diehard Randomness Test Suite (https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrandtest/).  All the algorithms have 3 methods to retrieve random numbers:

```
readByte()
readInt()
readLong()
```

Running a quick loop of the AES Algorithm generated these numbers:

```
Byte: -102
 Int: -252497821
Long: 5882262596119081845
Byte: -68
 Int: 1688727157
Long: 436050817787325007
```

I need to generate random integers in the range of 0-36 (inclusive).  None of the classes have a method similar to nextInt(int bound) that Random() and SecureRandom() have.  How to I fit the number I get from the PRNG into the range I need?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach would be to to take the result of `readInt() % myMaxValue` but this is going to produce skewed distributions because it uses the least-significant-bits of the generated values (which happens to have the lowest entropy).

Read the spec of [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) to get an idea of how they get around. And, of course, there is [the source of openjdk](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Random.java#Random.nextInt%28int%29) you can get inspiration from.

Comment: was just about to say the same thing in regards to reading grepcode and try to adapt to implementation